# Migrate Critical Magento Database Tables

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, ce-1.8.1.0

My client has a production server running CE 1.7.0.2. I am developing a new version of the site on CE 1.8.1.0. The new site includes a new theme, and shedding loads of the old modules and extensions.

Once the new site is ready, I'll want to transfer all the orders, customers, consignments, products, categories, etc. to the new site.

I DON'T want the data from the redundant modules, or the config stuff. Finally, my question; what's the best way to achieve this.

I have in mind to copy all the "critical" tables across, leaving out the `core_config_data`, `core_store`, etc. tables. Is this possible or am I dreaming? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible.
First thing that you need is to analyse what changes did all installed extensions to your database(Tables, attributes to eav model, changes to standard magento tables). 
Revert them. After replace your core_config_data from fresh Magento install or keep existing ones. And upgrade the code. 
After clean the cache to run sql updates.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this for future adventurers; I ended up getting the data from MySQL by NOT including the configuration tables in the `mysqldump`. Here's the tables I ignored in my export. This does not allow for any modules you might have:

```
mysqldump -u admin -p password mydatabase --ignore-table=core_config_data --ignore-table=core_resource --ignore-table=core_store --ignore-table=core_store_group --ignore-table=core_website --ignore-table=core_url_rewrite --ignore-table=cron_schedule --ignore-table=log_visitor_online --ignore-table=log_visitor_info --ignore-table=log_visitor --ignore-table=log_url_info --ignore-table=log_url --ignore-table=log_summary_type --ignore-table=log_summary --ignore-table=log_quote --ignore-table=log_customer --ignore-table=shipping_tablerate > mydatabase_today.sql
```

That left me with a MySQL dump that contained only the data from the site; orders, categories, products, etc. Use with caution!! USE WITH CAUTION! :)

-- edit - -

FYI, after importing the data to the new database, I re-installed all the modules I wanted.